# Angular2: unable to navigate to url using location.go(url)

Tags: location, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to navigate to a specific url using location.go service from typescript function. It changes the url in the browser but the component of the url is not reflected in the screen. It stays on the login (actual) screen - say for eg:

```
constructor(location: Location, public _userdetails: userdetails){
    this.location = location;
}
login(){
    if (this.username && this.password){
        this._userdetails.username = this.username;
        this.location.go('/home');
    }
    else{
        console.log('Cannot be blank');
    }
}
```

Is there a compile method or a refresh method I am missing?

Comment: try using `router.navigate(['your route'])`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, for redirecting from one route to another you should not be using `location.go`, it generally used to get `normalized url` on browser.

[**Location docs**](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Location-class.html) has strictly mentioned below note.

> Note: it's better to use Router service to trigger route changes. Use
>   Location only if you need to interact with or create normalized URLs
>   outside of routing.

Rather you should use `Router` API's `navigate` method, which will take `['routeName']` as you do it while creating `href` using `[routerLink]` directive.

If you wanted redirect via URL only then you could use [**`navigateByUrl`**](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl) which takes URL as string like `router.navigateByUrl(url)`

```
import { 
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, 
  RouteConfig, 
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
  Location, //note: in newer angular2 versions Location has been moved from router to common package
  Router 
} from 'angular2/router';

constructor(location: Location, 
            public _userdetails: userdetails,
            public _router: Router){
    this.location = location;
}
login(){
    if (this.username && this.password){
        this._userdetails.username = this.username;
        //I assumed your `/home` route name is `Home`
        this._router.navigate(['Home']); //this will navigate to Home state.
        //below way is to navigate by URL
        //this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')
    }
    else{
        console.log('Cannot be blank');
    }
}
```

**Update**

In further study, I found that, when you call `navigate`, basically it does accept `routeName` inside array, and if parameters are there then should get pass with it like `['routeName', {id: 1, name: 'Test'}]`.

Below is API of `navigate` function of `Router`.

```
Router.prototype.navigate = function(linkParams) {
  var instruction = this.generate(linkParams); //get instruction by look up RouteRegistry
  return this.navigateByInstruction(instruction, false);
};
```

When `linkParams` passed to `generate` function, it does return out all the [**Instruction**](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Instruction-class.html)'s required to navigate on other compoent. Here `Instruction` means [**`ComponentInstruction`**](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/ComponentInstruction-class.html)'s which have all information about Routing, basically what ever we register inside `@RouteConfig`, will get added to `RouteRegistry`(like on what `path` which `Component` should assign to to `router-outlet`).

Now retrieved Instruction's gets passed to `navigateByInstruction` method, which is responsible to load Component and will make various thing available to component like `urlParams` & parent & child component instruction, if they are there.

**Instruction (in console)**

```
auxInstruction: Object //<- parent instructions
child: null //<- child instructions
component: ComponentInstruction //<-current component object
specificity: 10000
urlParams: Array[0] <-- parameter passed for the route
urlPath: "about" //<-- current url path
```

> **Note:** Whole answer is based on older router version, when Angular 2 was in beta release.

Comment: Why would it not go through `location.go('url');` ? I was able to get router.navigate work. How do I enable through that? Do I have to listen for events and instantiate the component... I am unclear on this. Can you help?

Comment: @Gary I'll try to gather detail, why `location.go` not loading `route component`.. but why you relying on `url` bases route change(and Angular2 doc has also made not of not to use `Location` api to change route)?

Comment: I think using location.go at this point is incorrect use of it. I think they should have implement route change on location.go.. Hope still api is in beta release..hopefully angular2 will take care of this case.

Comment: @Gary look at updated answer.. I digged a little deeper in code and updated my understanding.. feel free to tell me if there is anyting wrong.

Comment: That is good explanation. specificity: 10000 is what? What purpose does it solve? And so if I call location.go, I might need to look at implementation of navigateByInstruction with a promise on route change. Is that correct or I got navigateByInstruction usage wrong?

Comment: @Gary yes. some how you need to put `listner/observable` over window location change event, and from that you could call `router.navigateByUrl('/home')` method.. then it will do desire functionality..

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this, though not sure if that will work. `Use Location only if you need to interact with or create normalized URLs outside of routing.`

Comment: I'll just add this here: import { Location } from 'angular2/platform/common';