# Change route params without reloading in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I'm making a real estate website using Angular 2, Google Maps, etc. and when a user changes the center of the map I perform a search to the API indicating the current position of the map as well as the radius. The thing is, I want to reflect those values in the url without reloading the entire page. Is that possible? I've found some solutions using AngularJS 1.x but nothing about Angular 2.

Comment: i think if you use [routerLink]="['/route', { param1: value1 }] it won't reload the page

Comment: but how can i add another query parameter?

Comment: ☝️ it will cause a page reload

Comment: Just a note that if you use SSR to make your site SEO compatible, this is a moot problem.

Comment: @Jonathan, is it? Since Angular takes over routing once the static page is rendered, I would think it's still a valid question even when using SSR.

Comment: just push to history...`window.history.pushState("http://example.ca", "Sample Title", "/example/path.html");`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You could use `location.go(url)` which will basically change your url, without change in route of application.

> **NOTE** this could cause other effect like redirect to child route from the current route.

[**Related question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35534112/2435473) which describes `location.go` will not intimate to `Router` to happen changes.

### How to

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private _location: Location){ }

updateUrl(url: string) {
  this._location.go(url)
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Now i have other things to deal with but changing the url is no longer on of those. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcosBasualdo Glad to know that...Thanks :) **but that might affect other thing**, technically it doesn't make sense with what you are doing.. are you only referencing parameters of your route?

Comment: I mean to say are you only changing route parameters?

Comment: My route has a parameter named 'search' in which a receive a serialized version of the search fields, when the listing state loads for the first time i only read those parameters using this._routeParams.get('search'), deserialize the filters and perform the search. If user changes the search fields, either by using the map or the search facets, i just construct the correct url using the method generate of the router 
var instruction = this._router.generate(['Listing',{search: serializedFields}]) and then using this._location.go(instruction.urlPath) to alter the url without reloading the state.

Comment: @MarcosBasualdo ok.. that make sense.. Angular2 need to provide `reloadOnSearch` option (angular1 have it), so that we can handle that stuff by router itself..

Comment: If anyone else is wondering: import { Location } from 'angular2/platform/common';

Comment: While this does work, I've found this technique causes the back button not to work the first time you press it. It will successfully change the url, but the state with not reload. However if you change the url twice or more and then use the back/forward buttons it all works. Thoughts?

Comment: `import { Location } from '@angular/common';` in Angular 4

Comment: I'm getting a typescript compilation error message: Property 'go' does not exist on type 'Location'.
I've imported the Location service, assigned it to 'location' in the constructor but then typescript starts giving me problems...

Comment: Did you decared constructr like `constructor(private location: Location){ }`

Comment: @AdrianE the problem is most probably that you typed `location.go()` while you should have typed `this.location.go()`. When you emit the `this.`, you call Typescript's location-interface.

Answer (score 173):

As of RC6 you can do the following to change URL without change state and thereby keeping your route history

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {Location} from '@angular/common'; 
// If you dont import this angular will import the wrong "Location"

@Component({
  selector: 'example-component',
  templateUrl: 'xxx.html'
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit
{
  constructor( private location: Location )
  {}

  ngOnInit()
  {    
    this.location.replaceState("/some/newstate/");
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It sitll tries to load the route. Console error: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'some/newstate'`

Comment: Combine this with url creation as suggested by @golfadas and we have a winner!

Answer (score 106):

Using `location.go(url)` is the way to go, but instead of hardcoding the url , consider generating it using `router.createUrlTree()`.

Given that you want to do the following router call: `this.router.navigate([{param: 1}], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})` but without reloading the component, it can be rewritten as:

```
const url = this.router.createUrlTree([], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: {param: 1}}).toString()

 this.location.go(url);
```

Comment: This answer solved my issue. One question, the url generated above is having parameters delimited by  ";"(semicolon). What should we do in order to separate each parameter in the query with "&"?

Comment: this is declaration of createUrlTree(commands: any[], navigationExtras?: NavigationExtras). 
you have to use queryParams located navigationExtras not commads. 
createUrlTree([], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: {param: 1} })

Comment: just to clarify on what @kit said, do this: `this.router.createUrlTree([], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: {param: 1}}).toString()`

Comment: This is a good idea, but with `location.go` this.activatedRoute will not change and so you will also add params to the old route…

Comment: How does this related to route parameters?

Answer (score 27):

For anyone like me finding this question the following might be useful.

I had a similar problem and initially tried using location.go and location.replaceState as suggested in other answers here. However I ran into problems when I had to navigate to another page on the app because the navigation was relative to the current route and the current route wasn't being updated by location.go or location.replaceState (the router doesn't know anything about what these do to the URL)

In essence I needed a solution that DIDN'T reload the page/component when the route parameter changed but DID update the route state internally.

I ended up using query parameters. You can find more about it here: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html

So if you need to do something like save an order and get an order ID you can update your page URL like shown below. Updating a centre location and related data on a map would be similar

```js
// let's say we're saving an order. Initally the URL is just blah/orders
save(orderId) {
    // [Here we would call back-end to save the order in the database]

    this.router.navigate(['orders'], { queryParams: { id: orderId } });
    // now the URL is blah/orders?id:1234. We don't reload the orders
    // page or component so get desired behaviour of not seeing any 
    // flickers or resetting the page.
}
```

and you keep track of it within the ngOnInit method like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.orderId = this.route
        .queryParamMap
        .map(params => params.get('id') || null);
    // orderID is up-to-date with what is saved in database now, or if
    // nothing is saved and hence no id query paramter the orderId variable
    // is simply null.
    // [You can load the order here from its ID if this suits your design]
}
```

If you need to go direct to the order page with a new (unsaved) order you can do:

```
this.router.navigate(['orders']);
```

Or if you need to go direct to the order page for an existing (saved) order you can do:

```
this.router.navigate(['orders'], { queryParams: { id: '1234' } });
```

Comment: Indeed, this correctly updates the route (from Angular perspective) do doesn't rebuild the component at `'orders'`, which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 17):

I had major trouble getting this to work in RCx releases of angular2.  The Location package has moved, and running location.go() inside constructor() wont work. It needs to be ngOnInit() or later in the lifecycle.  Here is some example code:

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-component',
  templateUrl: 'xxx.html'
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit
{
  constructor( private location: Location )
  {}

  ngOnInit()
  {    
    this.location.go( '/example;example_param=917' );
  }
}
```

Here are the angular resources on the matter:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/LocationStrategy-class.html

Answer (score 12):

I've had similar requirements as described in the question and it took a while to figure things out based on existing answers, so I would like to share my final solution.

**Requirements**

The state of my view (component, technically) can be changed by the user (filter settings, sorting options, etc.) When state changes happen, i.e. the user changes the sorting direction, I want to:

- Reflect the state changes in the URL
- Handle state changes, i.e. make an API call to receive a new result set

additionally, I would like to:

- Specify if the URL changes are considered in the browser history (back/forward)  based on circumstances
- use complex objects as state params to provide greater flexibility in handling of state changes (optional, but makes life easier for example when some state changes trigger backend/API calls while others are handled by the frontend internally)

**Solution: Change state without reloading component**

A state change *does not* cause a component reload when using route parameters or query parameters. The component instance stays alive. I see no good reason to mess with the router state by using `Location.go()` or `location.replaceState()`.

```
var state = { q: 'foo', sort: 'bar' }; 
var url = this.router.createUrlTree([], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: state }).toString();
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```

The `state` object will be transformed to URL query params by Angular's `Router`:

`https://localhost/some/route?q=foo&sort=bar`

**Solution: Handling state changes to make API calls**

The state changes triggered above can be handled by subscribing to `ActivatedRoute.queryParams`:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

   ngOnInit()
   {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
         // params is the state object passed to the router on navigation 
         // Make API calls here
      });
   }

}
```

The `state` object of the above axample will be passed as the `params` argument of the `queryParams` observable. In the handler API calls can be made if necessary.

But: I would prefer handling the state changes directly in my component and avoid the detour over `ActivatedRoute.queryParams`. IMO, navigating the router, letting Angular do routing magic and handle the `queryParams` change to do something, completely obfuscates whats happening in my component with regards to maintenability and readability of my code. What I do instead:

Compare the state passed in to `queryParams` observable with the current state in my component, do nothing, if it hasn't changed there and handle state changes directly instead:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   private _currentState;

   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

   ngOnInit()
   {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
         // Following comparison assumes, that property order doesn't change
         if (JSON.stringify(this._currentState) == JSON.stringify(params)) return;
         // The followig code will be executed only when the state changes externally, i.e. through navigating to a URL with params by the user
         this._currentState = params;
         this.makeApiCalls();
      });
   }

   updateView()
   {          
      this.makeApiCalls();
      this.updateUri();
   }    

   updateUri()
   {
      var url = this.router.createUrlTree([], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: this._currentState }).toString();
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
   }
}
```

**Solution: Specify browser history behavior**

```
var createHistoryEntry = true // or false
var url = ... // see above
this.router.navigateByUrl(url, { replaceUrl : !createHistoryEntry});
```

**Solution: Complex objects as state**

This is beyond the original question but adresses common scenarios and might thus be useful: The `state` object above is limited to flat objects (an object with only simple string/bool/int/... properties but no nested objects). I found this limiting, because I need to distinguish between properties that need to be handled with a backend call and others, that are only used by the component internally. I wanted a state object like:

```
var state = { filter: { something: '', foo: 'bar' }, viewSettings: { ... } };
```

To use this state as queryParams object for the router, it needs to be flattened. I simply `JSON.stringify` all first level properties of the object:

```
private convertToParamsData(data) {
    var params = {};

    for (var prop in data) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, prop)) {
        var value = data[prop];
        if (value == null || value == undefined) continue;
        params[prop] = JSON.stringify(value, (k, v) => {
          if (v !== null) return v
        });
      }
    }
    return params;
 }
```

and back, when handling the queryParams returned passed in by the router:

```
private convertFromParamsData(params) {
    var data = {};

    for (var prop in params) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(params, prop)) {
        data[prop] = JSON.parse(params[prop]);
      }
    }
    return data;
}
```

**Finally: A ready-to-use Angular service**

And finally, all of this isolated in one simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { map, filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class QueryParamsService {

  private currentParams: any;

  externalStateChange: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private location: Location) {

    this.externalStateChange = this.activatedRoute.queryParams
      .pipe(map((flatParams) => {
        var params = this.convertFromParamsData(flatParams);
        return params
      }))
      .pipe(filter((params) => {
        return !this.equalsCurrentParams(params);
      }))
      .pipe(tap((params) => {
        this.currentParams = params;
      }));
  }

  setState(data: any, createHistoryEntry = false) {
    var flat = this.convertToParamsData(data);
    const url = this.router.createUrlTree([], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: flat }).toString();
    this.currentParams = data;
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url, { replaceUrl: !createHistoryEntry });
  }

  private equalsCurrentParams(data) {
    var isEqual = JSON.stringify(data) == JSON.stringify(this.currentParams);
    return isEqual;
  }

  private convertToParamsData(data) {
    var params = {};

    for (var prop in data) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, prop)) {
        var value = data[prop];
        if (value == null || value == undefined) continue;
        params[prop] = JSON.stringify(value, (k, v) => {
          if (v !== null) return v
        });
      }
    }
    return params;
  }

  private convertFromParamsData(params) {
    var data = {};

    for (var prop in params) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(params, prop)) {
        data[prop] = JSON.parse(params[prop]);
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

which can be used like:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-search",
  templateUrl: "./search.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./search.component.scss"],
  providers: [QueryParamsService]
})
export class ProjectSearchComponent implements OnInit {

    filter : any;

    viewSettings : any;

    constructor(private queryParamsService: QueryParamsService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.queryParamsService.externalStateChange
          .pipe(debounce(() => interval(500))) // Debounce optional
          .subscribe(params => {
           // Set state from params, i.e.
           if (params.filter) this.filter = params.filter;
           if (params.viewSettings) this.viewSettings = params.viewSettings;

           // You might want to init this.filter, ... with default values here
           // If you want to write default values to URL, you can call setState here
            this.queryParamsService.setState(params, false); // false = no history entry

            this.initializeView(); //i.e. make API calls        
         });
     }

     updateView() {

       var data = {
         filter: this.filter,
         viewSettings: this.viewSettings
       };

       this.queryParamsService.setState(data, true);

       // Do whatever to update your view
     }

  // ...

}
```

Don't forget the `providers: [QueryParamsService]` statement on component level to create a new service instance for the component. Don't register the service globally on app module.

Answer (score 9):

I use this way to get it:

```
const queryParamsObj = {foo: 1, bar: 2, andThis: 'text'};

this.location.replaceState(
  this.router.createUrlTree(
    [this.locationStrategy.path().split('?')[0]], // Get uri
    {queryParams: queryParamsObj} // Pass all parameters inside queryParamsObj
  ).toString()
);
```

-- EDIT --

I think that I should add some more informations for this.

If you use `this.location.replaceState()` router of your application is not updated, so if you use router information later it's not equal for this in your browser. For example if you use `localizeService` to change language, after switch language your application back to last URL where you was before change it with `this.location.replaceState()`.

If you don't want this behaviour you can chose different method for update URL, like:

```
this.router.navigate(
  [this.locationStrategy.path().split('?')[0]],
  {queryParams: queryParamsObj}
);
```

In this option your browser also doesn't refresh but your `URL` change is also injected into `Router` of your application, so when you switch language you don't have problem like in `this.location.replaceState()`.

Of course you can choose method for your needs. The first is more lighter because you don't engage your application more than change `URL` in browser.

Answer (score 5):

Use attribute queryParamsHandling: 'merge' while changing the url.

```
this.router.navigate([], {
        queryParams: this.queryParams,
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
        replaceUrl: true,
});
```

Comment: This causes the currently routed component to be reloaded

Answer (score 4):

For me it was actually a mix of both with Angular 4.4.5.

Using router.navigate kept destroying my url by not respecting the realtiveTo: activatedRoute part.

I've ended up with:

```
this._location.go(this._router.createUrlTree([this._router.url], { queryParams: { profile: value.id } }).toString())
```

Answer (score 3):

In 2021 here is the solution I use. Create URL Tree using `createUrlTree` and navigate to route using `location`

```
//Build URL Tree
    const urlTree = this.router.createUrlTree(["/employee/"+this.employeeId],{
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: params,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });

//Update the URL 
this.location.go(urlTree.toString());
```

Comment: Checked in Angular 12 and it worked like a charm. Only I used `replaceState` method instead of `go` so that it replaces previous state and not adds to it. Handy when you have URL which ends with `/new` and then you want to replace `new` with an entity ID after saving it to DB.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to remove a query param of the url to prevent user to see it.

I found `replaceState` safer than location.go because the path with the old query params disappeared of the stack and user can be redo the query related with this query. So, I prefer it to do it:

`this.location.replaceState(this.router.url.split('?')[0]);`

Whit `location.go`, go to back with the browser will return to your old path with the query params and will keep it in the navigation stack.

`this.location.go(this.router.url.split('?')[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use activatedRoute.navigate() to change URL parameters and use snapshot (not subscribe) to call API if u don't want to call API when URL parameters change.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

   ngOnInit()
   {
      const params = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams;
         // params is the state object passed to the router on navigation 
         // Make API calls here
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: 'child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    
    constructor(
       private location: Location
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // you can put 'this.location.go()' method call in any another method
        this.location.go('parentRoute/anotherChildRoute');
    }
}
```

For me, it changes child route in browser, without any current component reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to update queryparams and navigate without reloading. By nature `activatedRoute.snapshot.queryparams` are readonly. And this turnaround approach solved my problem.

```
// Get queryparams
let state = Object.assign({}, this.route.snapshot.queryParams)

// Change parameters of url
state["z"] = "hi";
state["y"] = "bye";

// Create url and navigate to it without reloading
const url = this.router.createUrlTree([], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: state }).toString();
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```