# Angular 2 - add URL parameter on demand

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there some how using a code to add a new URL parameter, for example:

http://example.com/mypage?par=1&par2=2

I need in my code something like:

```
if (myVar == 'abc') { 
    // add a par3=3 without navigate/refresh the page - just to 
    // add a decoration on the URL for bookmarks purposes, 
    // for example: when user bookmark it and go back, 
    //I will be displaying the same dialog box 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change route params without reloading in angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Angulars [Location](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Location-class.html). In this way only the url gets updated, but the router is not navigating to it.

```
import {Location} from 'angular2/router';
 class Component {
  constructor(location: Location) {
    location.go('/foo');//Add your params here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html) and return `true` you can renavigate to the URL with the added parameter, without everything being reloaded.