# Angular 2 - replace history instead of pushing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How to replace a history instead a pushing a new in angular 2's new router (rc.1)?

For example Im in a question list (`/questions`) opening a new modal in a new route (`/questions/add`), and after adding a new question I go to the question view (`/questions/1`). If I press back I would like to go to the `/questions` instead of `/questions/add`

Comment: have you tried 'canDeactivate' guard for your route '/questions/1'? Just check the desired destination, if it is '../add', redirect to '/questions'?
Or implement 'canActivate' for '../add' route instead..

Comment: too much complicated. i have hundred of places where I need this behaviour and guards with redirects are just monkey patches that will produce lot of code

Answer (score 120):

If you use

```
router.navigate
```

And then

```
location.replaceState
```

With the exact same path, you can trigger changes that usually happen, as well as replacing the history.

For example, in your case:

```
this.router.navigate(['questions/1']);
this.location.replaceState('questions/1');
```

If you need to add parameters to the route, you can create the url for location using

```
router.serializeUrl(router.createUrlTree(/* what you put in your router navigate call */));
```

In your example:

```
this.router.navigate(['questions/1', {name:"test"}]);
this.location.replaceState(this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(['questions/1', {name:"test"}])));
```

## Update

It seems the angular router now comes with a [replace url option](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl). In your example:

```
this.router.navigate(["questions/1"], {replaceUrl:true});
```

## Update 2

There is a current [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18036) where multiple navigations done in a short amount of time may not replace the URL correctly. As a temporary workaround, wrap the navigate function in a timeout to get each to fire in a separate cycle:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.router.navigate(["questions/1"], {replaceUrl:true});
});
```

Comment: Note: For [routerLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) directives, you can add a `replaceUrl` attribute to the element for the same effect.

Comment: The only caveat to using `router.navigate` and `{ replaceUrl: true }` is it will register another navigation event. If you are listening to navigation events (eg, `NavigationEnd`) and don't want two events to fire, `location.replaceState` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, @Jason for your Update 2 and specifying the issue we have in angular. It was able to resolve my case in Angular 6 by using setTimeout().

Comment: Note that `{replaceUrl: true}` is also available as an extra option to `router.createUrlTree()`, which means you can use it when returning an `Observable<UrlTree>` from a `CanActivate` guard (instead of having to resort to explicit router navigation).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2

Answer (score 5):

You want to use replaceState from the Locations class

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html#!#replaceState-anchor

Comment: yeah I saw that api, but I need api from router to make sure router works and updates smoothly

Comment: the url is invalid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2