# How to tell router to skip previous url in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a component that redirect to another url:

```
http://mysite.domain/#/url
```

If it's empty I want to redirect it to another:

```
this._router.navigate(['url/suburl'])
```

But my problem is that when the user go to previous url it will trigger my redirection, the question is how to skip an url with angular router?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079352/1009922). Try: `this._router.navigate(["url/suburl"], {replaceUrl:true});`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thank you very much exactly what I needed!