# UI-Router for Angular: Is it possible to update location without reloading the page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am migrating an app from AngularJs to Angular 7. In the old ui-router I was able to update the location without reloading the state with below code.

```js
        this.syncLocation = function (paramObj) {
            var params = _.clone($state.params);
            params = _.merge(params, paramObj);

            $state.transitionTo($state.current.name, params, {
                location: true,
                notify: false
            });
        };
```

However with new Angular & UI-Router I am unable to get this done. Not sure if it is due to Change Detection Strategy or changes to UI-Router itself.

```ts
  syncLocation(paramObj) {
    console.log("syncLocation", paramObj);
    let params = _.clone(this.stateService.params);
    params = _.merge(params, paramObj);

    this.stateService.go(this.stateService.current.name, params, {
      reload: false
    });
  }
```

I have created [plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cuv997?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcolors.component.ts) to reproduce the problem. The problem is described in the component `colors.component.ts` [link](https://angular-cuv997.stackblitz.io/#/colors?theme=false). In this plunker I don't want to reload the page even though I check/uncheck the checkbox.

The idea is that I have a complicated page where I cannot afford to lose the contents by reloading the page but still be able to update the location. It is a simplified page with the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: its already been answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079352/9590251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the url with `Location.replaceState()`

See: [replaceState()](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#replacestate)

Inject `Location` with di and use like this:

```
constructor(private location: Location) {
...
  private syncLocation(){
    this.location.replaceState(`whatever/state/or/path/you/need`);
  }
}
```

There are other useful methods in `Location` such as `Path` you may want to reference.