# Redirect to 404 component without changing browser URL and make history behave right in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

When my backend sends me a `404` error (URL is valid, just because the resource is not found, like `http://localhost:4200/post/title-not-exist`), I want Angular redirect to my `NotFoundComponent`, without changing the URL in browser.

Code below (simplified):

```js
constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) {}

handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
  switch (err.status) {
    case 404:
      url = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
      // '**' is set in the app-routing.module.ts
      // { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
      this.router.navigate(['**'], { replaceUrl: false });
      // weird here too
      // without the setTimeout(), replaceState will not work
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.location.replaceState(url);
      });
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
  return throwError(err);
}
```

Now, I can redirect to `NotFoundComponent` and the URL not changed, the problem is:

1. My history will become things like:
   `/post/title-exist` → `/post/not-exist` → `/post/not-exist`
   which should be
   `/post/title-exist` → `/post/not-exist`
   And the go back function will stuck here.
2. Without the `setTimeout()`, `location.replaceState()` will not work, the URL in browser becomes `/**` and not changing to the URL that snapshotted before.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in stackblitz ?

Comment: @dota2pro I have to send a mock 404 status from backend, can stackblitz do that?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend

Comment: you can also create a mock api online https://www.mockable.io/a/#/try or just pass a json object after a timeout ?????? what is the need of an API for demo

Comment: What dont you just hide/show NotFoundComponent based on the API return status, instead of using the router? And when you show that component, hide your `<router>`

Comment: @David you mean by using `*ngIf` to hide/show component? Does that mean I have to make my `post.component.html` become `<app-post *ngIf="!notFound"></app-post><app-not-found *ngIf="notFound"></app-not-found>`? But I think it's not a good practice since I may have to add `NotFoundComponent` to these components manually.

Comment: I assumed that the `NotFoundComponent` was the same for the whole application.  So when your service returns a 404, your `PostComponent`  can catch that error, broadcast a message to tell your root component to show the `NotFoundComponent` and hide the `<router>` outlet. You could even do it in a more generic way where an interceptor does that for all your API requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

Use `skipLocationChange` to keep the original URL, `replaceUrl` is not needed anymore.
Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37055297/10684507).

**Original**

The key point is to change the `replaceUrl` in `this.router.navigate` from `false` to `true`, like this:

```js
this.router.navigate(['**'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

Logic behind:

- When `replaceUrl` is `false`, you are [pushing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) a new history to your browser history stack. So the history stack becomes like this:

`/post/title-exist` → `/post/title-not-exist` → `/**`

And with the help of `replaceState()`, it changes the `/**` history to `/post/title-not-exist`, which makes the history finally becomes:

`/post/title-exist` → `/post/title-not-exist` → <del>`/**`</del> `/post/title-not-exist`

- When `replaceUrl` is `true`, you are directly [modifying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) the current history stack, which makes your browser history becomes like this:

`/post/title-exist` → <del>`/post/title-not-exist`</del> `/**`

Then, with the help of `replaceState()`, the history becomes:

`/post/title-exist` → <del>`/post/title-not-exist`</del> <del>`/**`</del> `/post/title-not-exist`

Comment: But I'm still confusing about why `location.replaceState()` will not work without `setTimeout()`. Don't know if it's related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39079352/10684507) answer.