# chrome exits the angular app on clicking hardware backbutton

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i have setup my route links like this

1. matches screen

http://localhost:4200/#/nav/matches

2. my profile

http://localhost:4200/#/nav/my-profile

3. edit profile

http://localhost:4200/#/nav/edit-profile

4. my photos

http://localhost:4200/#/nav/my-photos

5. settings

http://localhost:4200/#/nav/settings

6. my orders

http://localhost:4200/#/nav/my-orders

the problem iam facing is whenever i clicks the hardware back button after navigation through all these pages

app exits to goole default screen or some other url i searched before (like https://stackoverflow.com/)
some times it comes to matches screen which is my default screen and exits ( navigating away from my site )

i want to go back to previous page of my application instead of exiting directly like

5 ==> 4==> 3 ==> 2 ==> 1 ==> exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected behaviour is because in my project to navigate to another routes we were using

```
    this.router.navigateByUrl(link, {replaceUrl: true});
```

this replaces history
thanks to [Angular 2 - replace history instead of pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891002/angular-2-replace-history-instead-of-pushing)

then i changed that to

```
    this.router.navigateByUrl(link);
```

and the issue fixed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).