# Angular filter router history elements

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Given an app that uses `Router` for navigation, how can I filter out specific router history elements from the history?

E.g. can I do something like this, where I get and filter away all urls with 'xyz' in them:

```
// pseudo code

history = this.router.getHistory();
filtered = history.filter(x => !x.url.contains('xyz'));
this.router.setHistory(filtered);
```

The goal is that the browser's history should now not contain the 'xyz' urls, so if pressing 'Back', 'xyz' urls should not be navigated even if they were previously in the history.

Comment: is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891002/angular-2-replace-history-instead-of-pushing) help you? in shortly: use `LocationClass.replaceState` function, or add props `replaceUrl` to your `router.navigate`. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Add `skipLocationChange: true` as options on navigate

```
// Navigate silently to /example  
this.router.navigate(['/example'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```