# Change URL with Angular 2 RC6 Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am building a list app, where list-items can be selected.
Only one item can be selected at a time.
A detail-view for the list-item is displayed below the list.

Now I want to change the url based on which item is selected, without navigating to another page.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: Check out my answer at the bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2/39322473#39322473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use route parameters for this

```ts
{ path: '', redirectTo, 'items', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'items', component: ItemList, children: [
  { path: '', component: DummyItem },
  { path: ':id/detail', component: ItemDetails }
]}
```

```ts
<a [routerLink]="itemId + '/detail'">Item {{itemId}}</a>
```

```ts
class ItemDetail {
  constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe(params => this.id = params['id']);
  }
}
```

With a router navigation, when only route params change, nothing is reloaded.

Comment: I have used the solution provided in the following answer, since it was easier to implement with what I have. In case of refactoring my code, I will use the approach you provided. Thanks.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2/39322473#39322473