# How to set or remove queryParams in current route in angular 2 without reloading page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this current route:

```
http://localhost:96/#/pages/settings/devices
```

I want to set queryParams={name:realTime} to this current route like:

```
http://localhost:96/#/pages/settings/devices?name=realTime
```

Is it possible to add or remove queryParams to the current route without reloading the page?

I got the solution for this.

This will not reload Current page

```
let navigationExtra: NavigationExtras = {
relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
skipLocationChange: false,
queryParams: { name: 'realTime' }
}
    this.router.navigate(['./', navigationExtra]);
```

Comment: You're using `#` in your URL, indicating an SPA. That is; your page won't reload from the server. If you're bound to the URL, components may update. Otherwise, this question boils down to how to update a route via angular, of which there are plenty of examples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change route params without reloading in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2)

Comment: I got the solution for this.

This will not reload Current page 

    let navigationExtra: NavigationExtras = {
    relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
    skipLocationChange: false,
    queryParams: { name: 'realTime' }
    }
        this.router.navigate(['./', navigationExtra]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add or remove queryParams to current route without realoading the page.

Just change the location hash e.g.

```
window.location.hash = "/pages/settings/devices?name=realTime"
```

## More

The code I presented will work fine. However if you want it to have an impact in the state of your app, you should really check the docs on your *router* on how to navigate OR write your effects inline with that hash change.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the URL without having the router executing navigation build the URL tree and set it on the current location. Don't build the URL by hand.

```
 const url = this
        .router
        .createUrlTree([{param1: value1, paramN: valueN}], {relativeTo: this.ar})
        .toString();

 this.location.go(url);
```

location was injected in the component constructor:

```
import { DecimalPipe, Location } from '@angular/common';
constructor(private location: Location){}
```