# How can i change URL after get data from resolver in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I want to change my url `/blog/:id` to `/blog/blog-title` after i get blog title from resolver. Example: When i navigate to `blog/1` and the blog with id 1 has title `how-can-i-make-this` then the url should be `/blog/how-can-i-make-this`. How can i do this in angular 4?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: i have searched with keywords like "change url without reloading in angular", "slug url in angular"... but nothings solves my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Angular's router and use its navigate function:

**Typescript**

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router'; // import the router


constructor(private router:Router){} //put this in your contructor

// call this when you want to change you want to change the url
somefunction() {
  this.router.navigate(['how-can-i-make-this']).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

If you don't want to reload then see this answer:
[Change route params without reloading in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried location.go() and it's great. But i want when i refresh the browser with url '/blog/how-can-i-make-this' it should navigate to the same. May be something like '/blog/how-can-i-make-this-1' and i can get the id in the end?

Answer (score 0):

try below,

```
window.history.pushState(null, "Title", "/<blog-title>");
```

read more about pushState() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method).

Comment: I would recommend to use the router service instead of the window object.

Comment: I used location.go() and the result is great. Thank you anyway, i will read more about pushState()