# Angular router: (TAB like) navigate - how to change URL without running ngOnInit again

Tags: angular, router

OK, the question is simple, but don't seem to find the answer myself, so please help

I have this routes (simplified):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: ListPageComponent},
  {path: 'd/:id', component: DetailsPageComponent},
  {path: ':param1', component: ListPageComponent},
  {path: ':param1/:param2', component: ListPageComponent},
  {path: ':param1/:param2/:param3', component: ListPageComponent},
  {path: '**', component: ListPageComponent}
];
```

On the ListPageComponent I have some select box filters on top, that trigger onFilter method (simplified):

```
onFilter(filters: any) {
  this._router.navigate([
    'myroute/',
    this.param1,
    this.param2,
    this.param3
  ]);
}
```

Now, what I would like is when I trigger this method, and I navigate (to the same page component), I don't want the component to run ngOnInit again... just to change the URL params (I am already subscribed to params change -
 this._route.params.subscribe)

Comment: Did you try navigating relatively to the `ActivatedRoute`? I think that shouldn't reload your component but I'm not that sure, since I've only done it with `queryParams`.

Comment: Btw, looking at your routes and since you're using some kind of form element, I think you should be better off with `queryParams` instead.

Comment: @OsmanCea is right. With router params you will have different component for each route - so you can have the same component only if previous route has the same shape. But with queryParams you can describe everything with one route = one component initialization.

Comment: well, they have to be different routes like /myroute/param1/param2/...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution: [Change route params without reloading in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618463/change-route-params-without-reloading-in-angular-2)

it is possible just to use location.replaceState, works like a charm in my case!