# How to update/append the url in Angular7

Tags: angular, routes

I would like to append the browser url based on the view enabled in the same page.

Default URL: http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines

On click on the table row it will update like URL: http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=1100

```
onRowClicked(event: any) {
    this.isRowSelected = true;
    this.selectedId = event.data.id; //event.id;
    this.selectedItem = event;
    console.log(this.selectedItem);
    this.dataService.set(event);
    this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { disciplineId: this.selectedId } });

  }
```

1. Can not we update the selected ID automatically without using `this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { disciplineId: this.selectedId } });`
2. How to append the new value like `http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=1100&disciplineView=create` on clicking on some button.

If I use this  `this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { disciplineView: view } });`

url changed to

`http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineView=create`

instead

`http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=1100&disciplineView=create`

Expert advise please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 updating URL path params with no redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787379/angular-2-updating-url-path-params-with-no-redirect)

Comment: If I get your question right, On first click of the button, you need `http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=1100` and on the second click of the same button you need `http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=1100&disciplineView=create`?

Comment: If you want the above, you should use `queryParamsHandling: "merge"` . like this:  `this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { disciplineView: view }, queryParamsHandling: "merge" });`

Comment: Check this link for more [info](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#queryParamsHandling).

Comment: @KiraAG: No, While clicking the table row item url needs to update based on the selected item like "http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=1100". While clicking the create button outside the table url needs to be 'http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=1100&disciplineView=create'

Comment: Ok you can follow my option on using `queryParamsHandling: "merge"` above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `queryParamsHandling: "merge"` . like this: `this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { disciplineView: view }, queryParamsHandling: "merge" });`

So this will merge your new params to the existing activated route.