# Change url without redirect in angular 7

Tags: angular

I would like to add a path to the url, without redirecting the page.

like I am on page /home/ I want to move to /home/item1 without triggering a redirection.

I found many example on stack, but none of them work in angular 7.

location.go or location.replaceState are not available from

```
constructor(private location: Location) { }
```

I am trying to find a way in angular 7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use [Angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

```
this.router.navigate(['/mypath']);
```

Comment: He asked that it should not redirect. But I think the solution you gave will redirect.

Answer (score 5):

Other solutions here :
[Angular2: unable to navigate to url using location.go(url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533783/angular2-unable-to-navigate-to-url-using-location-gourl/35534112#35534112)

Using:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common'; 

constructor(private location: Location){}

location.go('myurl');
```

works for me :)

Comment: Although this works, its worth noting that it will not trigger any navigation events
So if you're tracking urls, via NavigationEnd events, this will not be picked up.